# Matrix algebra properties $c^{T}x + v^{T}(Ax-b) - \lambda^{T}x$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

My lectures notes are showing that:

$$c^{T}x + v^{T}(Ax-b) - \lambda^{T}x = -b^{T}v + (c+A^{T}v - \lambda)^{T}x$$

However, I cannot see how we we need to use the property that the transpose of the sum is the sum of the transpose. My way of thinking about that is:

$$c^{T}x + v^{T}(Ax-b) - \lambda^{T}x = (c^{T}+v^{T}A- \lambda^{T})x - v^{T}b$$

Wouldn't that be correct too?

Comment: These are both correct. The notes might have just wanted to write the $x$ term in the form $d^Tx$, which could be why they grouped everything into the transpose.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I now see it